AdMob ads not showing in TestFlight after replacing test AdUnit ID with production AdUnit ID in React Native (Expo)
I have integrated AdMob in my React Native app using Expo and react-native-google-mobile-ads. Locally, using the test AdUnit ID (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6978759866), everything works fine in the simulator, and I can see the ads without any issues. However, when I switch to my production AdUnit ID (ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx) provided by AdMob and build the app using Expo, I cannot see the ads either in the Expo Go app or in TestFlight.
Here's my setup:
app.json configuration:
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "plugins": [
      [
        "react-native-google-mobile-ads",
        {
          "androidAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx",
          "iosAppId": "ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "ios": {
      ...
      "infoPlist": {
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": [
              "cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork",
              "4fzdc2evr5.skadnetwork",
              ...
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

AdMob component code:
import { RewardedInterstitialAd, RewardedAdEventType, TestIds, AdEventType } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const adUnitId = 'ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx'; // Production Ad Unit ID

const rewardedInterstitial = RewardedInterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
  keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
});

const RewardedInterstitialAdComponent = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeLoaded = rewardedInterstitial.addAdEventListener(RewardedAdEventType.LOADED, () => {
      console.log('Ad loaded');
      setLoaded(true);
    });

    const unsubscribeEarned = rewardedInterstitial.addAdEventListener(RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD, (reward) => {
      console.log('User earned reward', reward);
    });

    const unsubscribeClosed = rewardedInterstitial.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.CLOSED, () => {
      rewardedInterstitial.load();
    });

    rewardedInterstitial.load();

    return () => {
      unsubscribeLoaded();
      unsubscribeEarned();
      unsubscribeClosed();
    };
  }, []);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  rewardedInterstitial.show();

  return <View style={styles.container} />;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default RewardedInterstitialAdComponent;

Problem:

Locally, using the test AdUnit ID, I can see the ads on the
simulator.
After switching to the real production AdUnit ID, ads do    not show
in TestFlight, or when using Expo Go after the production    build.
I have ensured that the AdUnit ID is correct in both the    app.json
and the AdMob console.
I am not sure if this is a    configuration    issue or if it’s
normal not to see ads in TestFlight.

Question:

Is this behavior normal for TestFlight (not showing real ads during
app review)?
Should I expect the ads to work once the app is live on
the App Store, or am I missing something in my configuration?


This is expected for development mode. You can use __DEV__ to define different IDs.
export default {
  BANNER: __DEV__ ? TestIds.BANNER : BANNER_ID,
  INTERSTITIAL: __DEV__ ? TestIds.INTERSTITIAL : INTERSTITIAL_ID,
};

Also for new apps, it can take some time to show ads, as per docs:

New iOS apps will not show Google ads until they’re listed in the Apple App Store

